# Gradle build fails due to sun.security.validator.ValidatorException despite installing certificates

Tags: java, macos, gradle, java-8, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to run [lenskit-hello](https://github.com/lenskit/lenskit-hello) according to their instructions. When I run `./gradlew build`, I receive the error

```
(base) Briennas-MBP:lenskit-hello-master briennakh$ ./gradlew build
:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve org.lenskit:lenskit-all:3.0-M3.
  Required by:
      :lenskit-hello-master 4.50.57 AM:unspecified
   > Could not resolve org.lenskit:lenskit-all:3.0-M3.
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/lenskit/lenskit-all/3.0-M3/lenskit-all-3.0-M3.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/lenskit/lenskit-all/3.0-M3/lenskit-all-3.0-M3.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
   > Could not resolve org.lenskit:lenskit-all:3.0-M3.
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/lenskit/lenskit-all/3.0-M3/lenskit-all-3.0-M3.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/lenskit/lenskit-all/3.0-M3/lenskit-all-3.0-M3.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.009 secs
```

I am using Java 1.8.0_241 (and only that one is installed) on MacOS Mojave 10.14.6. I've installed the most recent security updates, then restarted my computer. I have attempted this on my regular wifi and on my phone's hotspot.

I followed instructions in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore), downloading the security certificates from both `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/lenskit/lenskit-all/3.0-M2/lenskit-all-3.0-M2.pom` and `https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/lenskit/lenskit-all/3.0-M2/lenskit-all-3.0-M2.pom` and adding them to the keystore via the following command (only showing one of two):

```
keytool -import -alias maven -file /Users/briennakh/Downloads/maven.cer -keystore 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Then if I check

```
keytool -list -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts | grep maven
```

it shows that my certificate has been added, `maven, Mar 17, 2020, trustedCertEntry`, yet I'm still getting the same error when running `./gradlew build`?

I also checked `openssl x509 -in /Users/briennakh/Downloads/maven.pem -text` to make sure that the certificate looks all right.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you sure that `JAVA_HOME` environment variable correctly points to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk`?

Comment: It points to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home` @michalk

Comment: I set this with `echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 8):

That [SSL certificate](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=repo1.maven.org) is not self-signed to begin with, therefore it does not require manual adding. Try re-installing Java or set an alternate install location as `$JAVA_HOME`, with a default `cacerts` file. Something seems to be broken, as it should not reject the certificate for [`repo1.maven.org`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2). `ls -la $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` says `cacerts` should have about 114757 bytes. If you're behind a firewall, you might need to [configure a proxy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy) for Gradle.

This should attempt an SSL session (not through Java):

```
$ openssl s_client -connect repo1.maven.org:443
```

---

This project also uses a rather [outdated version](https://github.com/lenskit/lenskit-hello/blob/master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties#L6) of Gradle, eg:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Comment: I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Java, wiping my computer and reinstalling the OS. I have tried on my wifi, my school's wifi, my phone's hotspot. When I open that SSL session, I see these lines among other lines: `Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate` and `Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)` -- is this normal?

Comment: I followed the steps in http://movingpackets.net/2015/03/18/telling-openssl-about-your-root-certificates/ and got that openssl command to return ok by specifying `-CAfile`, so I exported the CAfile to SSL_CERT_FILE. But the problem still is there with java

Comment: `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts` should be the same as passing `-CAfile`. Try `keytool -list -v -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts | grep DigiCert` to see if that keystore works and knows about DigiCert, which is the issuer of the certificate in question.

Comment: `openssl s_client -CAfile $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -connect repo1.maven.org:443` would _eventually_ connect with `openssl`, but still use the Java keystore (assuming it can read the format). This would be the CA certificate required to validate the chain: [DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.crt](http://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.crt)

Answer (score 1):

Setting my project Gradle JDK version to that used by JAVA_HOME solved it

[image]

[image]

[image]