# IntelliJ Gradle dependency download

Tags: intellij-idea

I am not able setup my corda project using intelliJ, its not downloading the dependencies with company proxy. But same URL can be accessed from the browser without any issue. I tried Check connection from IntelliJ IDE and the connection is success . Please find the screenshots of the issues
Gradle sync issue[[image: Gradle Sync][1]]

[image]

Comment: Hello! Does it work if you build from command line outside IDE? Please try to set proxy in Gradle settings: https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-proxy-configuration

Comment: Its failing from command line

Comment: If I build with  --stacktrace  I am getting  Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certifi
cation path to requested target

Comment: It means that there is a problem with establishing a secure HTTPS connection. Please try suggestions from related discussions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60720241/gradle-build-fails-due-to-sun-security-validator-validatorexception-despite-inst, https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-build-pkix-path-building-failed/47651